# Convert Dask Bag of Pandas DataFrames to a single Dask DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

**Summary of Problem**

*Short Version*

How do I go from a Dask Bag of Pandas DataFrames, to a single Dask DataFrame?

*Long Version*

I have a number of files that are not readable by any of dask.dataframe's various `read` functions (e.g. `dd.read_csv` or `dd.read_parquet`). I do have my own function that will read them in as Pandas DataFrames (function only works on one file at a time, akin to `pd.read_csv`). I would like to have all of these single Pandas DataFrames in one large Dask DataFrame.

**Minimum Working Example**

Here's some example CSV data (my data isn't actually in CSVs, but using it here for ease of example). To create a minimum working example, you can save this as a CSV and make a few copies, then use the code below

```
"gender","race/ethnicity","parental level of education","lunch","test preparation course","math score","reading score","writing score"
"female","group B","bachelor's degree","standard","none","72","72","74"
"female","group C","some college","standard","completed","69","90","88"
"female","group B","master's degree","standard","none","90","95","93"
"male","group A","associate's degree","free/reduced","none","47","57","44"
"male","group C","some college","standard","none","76","78","75"
```

```py
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import dask.bag as db

files = glob('/path/to/your/csvs/*.csv')
bag = db.from_sequence(files).map(pd.read_csv)
```

**What I've tried so far**

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.bag as db
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Create a Dask bag of pandas dataframes
bag = db.from_sequence(list_of_files).map(my_reader_function)

df = bag.map(lambda x: x.to_records()).to_dataframe() # this doesn't work
df = bag.map(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient = <any option>)).to_dataframe() # neither does this

# This gets me really close. It's a bag of Dask DataFrames. 
# But I can't figure out how to concatenate them together
df = bag.map(dd.from_pandas, npartitions = 1)

df = dd.from_delayed(bag) # returns an error
```

Comment: The example data you have provided can easily be converted to a pandas data frame, saved as different files and the latter can be read into a single dask data frame. So, it is not clear why you need to use a dask bag and a conversion from it to a dask data frame.

Comment: You ask a good question. I should clarify: I have several million of these files that I need to read in, each anywhere from a few KB to many MB. Hence, I do not have the space to create dask-readable copies of the files.

Comment: If your custom read function outputs a single pandas data frame, can't you convert the output to a dask data frame, and keep doing this and appending to the dask data frame?

Comment: This is indeed pretty close to what I want! However, I have yet to find a way to do this that doesn't read in all of the files into memory at the same time. `bag = db.from_sequence(files).map(pd.read_csv).map(dd.from_pandas, npartitions=1)` and then `dd.concat(bag.compute())` will indeed work; but it reads everything into memory, which won't work for millions of files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using dask.delayed with dask.dataframe.  There is a good example doing what you want to do here:

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Can't believe I hadn't seen this page before. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two additional possible solutions:

**1. Convert the bag to a list of dataframes then use [dd.multi.concat](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.multi.concat.html):**

```
bag #a dask bag of dataframes
list_of_dfs = bag.compute()
df = dd.multi.concat(list_of_dfs).compute()
```

**2. Convert to a bag of dictionaries and use [bag.to_dataframe](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.bag.Bag.to_dataframe.html#dask.bag.Bag.to_dataframe):**

```
bag_of_dicts = bag.map(lambda df: df.to_dict(orient='records')).flatten()
df = bag_of_dicts.to_dataframe().compute()
```

In my own specific use case, option #2 had better performance than option #1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `concat` function from Dask to concatenate the Pandas DataFrames within the Dask Bag into a single Dask DataFrame. Here's how you can do it:

```py
import dask.bag as db
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Assuming `bag_of_dfs` is your Dask Bag of Pandas DataFrames
bag_of_dfs = ...

# Convert each Pandas DataFrame in the Bag to a Dask DataFrame
dask_dfs = bag_of_dfs.map(dd.from_pandas)

# Concatenate the Dask DataFrames into a single Dask DataFrame
concatenated_df = dd.concat(dask_dfs)
```

Now `concatenated_df` will be a single Dask DataFrame containing all the data from the Pandas DataFrames within the Dask Bag.

https://coiled.io/blog/how-to-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-dask-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a bag of dataframes then you can do the following:

1. Convert bag to delayed partitions,
2. convert delayed partitions to delayeds of dataframes by concatenating,
3. create dataframe from these delayeds.

In python code:

```
def bag_to_dataframe(bag, **concat_kwargs):
    partitions = bag.to_delayed()
    dataframes = map(
        dask.delayed(lambda partition: pandas.concat(partition, **concat_kwargs)),
        partitions
    )
    return dask.dataframe.from_delayed(dataframes)
```

You might want to control the concatenation of partitions, for example to ignore the index.